# jQuery ajax plugin get entered value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-autocomplete

I am using jQuery [autocomplete plugin](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete) to get values from database using this plugin. As per demo I made my code like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
        serviceUrl: 'ajax.php',        
      });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="autocomplete">

</body>
</html>
```

Now when I am doing any search. Then in console tab I can see the ajax request like this

```
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost/ajax.php?query=united
```

additionally it is showing one error in console tab like

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <  in jquery-2.1.0-min.js:4
```

Now to get the value of query string in ajax.php I did like this

```
$value = $_POST['query];
echo $value;
```

But it is not showing any value. So can someone tell me how to get the input entered values in the ajax.php file? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are using Google Chrome, aren't you?
It would be helpful to see what data is actually transfered...
Try to hit F12, open the "Network" tab, click on the item that shows up when the AJAX request is made, and check the output in the "Response" sub tab.
My assumption: You're facing some syntax error in your PHP file that outputs HTML tags as part of an error message.
BTW: Your PHP code contains a syntax error, the ' after index "query" on line 1 is missing...

Comment: AVM is also right, of course. You're reading from $_POST whereas your JS is doing a GET request...